# about the the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Because I'm a beginner in those stuffs I find some difficulties in the following (Using the universal property of the tensor product)

> prove that $\mathbb {Q}\otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}$
>
> let $a$,$b$ $\in \mathbb{N}^*$, prove that $(a\mathbb{Z})\otimes (b\mathbb{Z}) \cong ab\mathbb {Z}$

My attemp is:

> let $f:\mathbb {Q} \times \mathbb {Q}\rightarrow \mathbb {Q} \otimes \mathbb {Q}$.
>
> We consider $g:\mathbb {Q} \times \mathbb {Q}\rightarrow \mathbb {Q}$ with $ g(a,b)=ab$
>
> $g$ **is well defined**, indeed: let $(a,b),(a',b')\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $(a,b)=(a',b')$, then $a=a'$ and $b=b'$, so $ab=a'b'$.
>
> $g$ **is bilinear**, indeed: let $a,b,a',b',\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$then
>
> $g(a+a',b)=g(a,b)+g(a',b)$, $g(\lambda a,b)=\lambda g(a,b)$, $g(a,b+b')=g(a,b)+g(a,b')$, $g(a,\lambda b)=\lambda g(a,b)$. So $g$ is bilinear.
>
> according to the universal property of the product tensorial, there exist a unique application $h$ such that $h o f=g$.
>
> we consider $k: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb {Q}$

I have to show: $k$ is well-defined, linear, $k\circ h$ is equal to the identity and $h\circ k$ is equal to the identity, but I don't know how to take the elements of the function??

any hints, how to define $k$.

in the second part I have to do the same so

> I take $g:a\mathbb{Z} \times b\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow ab\mathbb{Z}$ with $g(a\alpha,b\beta)=ab\alpha\beta$

is it the good function I have to take or not?

and about the inverse function $k$ I always have a problem of finding it, any hints

Thank you.

Comment: What ring is the tensor product over? Sur quel anneau prenez-vous les produits tensoriels?

Comment: You don't need to mention that $g$ is well-defined. Its domain isn't a quotient set. You can choose $k(x) = x \otimes 1$. To prove that $k \circ h = \operatorname{id}$, you'll need to use some specific properties of $\mathbb{Q}$. (This assumes the tensor products are over $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: I think it is a $A$ (un $A$ quelconque)

Comment: Non, il faut au moins que $\mathbb{Q}$ soit un $A$-module. A priori, pour que ça ait un sens, on s'attendrait à ce que ce soit un sous-anneau de $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @David thank you very much, and the second part is my $g$ a good choice

Comment: @David I don't understand why you start to speak French here.

Comment: That question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. All the modules are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: @FrankScience Because in the circumstances, it seemed that communication with Meriem would be easiest in French. If you care a lot about this, I can translate my comments for you or delete them.

Comment: @David The point is that MSE is not only for the OPs but also for others, and for reference, not like a chat room. You needn't translate it for me, but if you're pleased, translate for audience, since English is the *lingua franca*. What about deleting? Well, apparently it will *reduce* the number of beneficiaries, so no need to do that.

Comment: Frank, in this case I was writing primarily for Meriem. I've read numerous times that "comments are meant to be ephemeral", or something to that effect. If someone specifically requests that I translate the comments for them because they are genuinely interested in their content, I would be happy to. If you think this would have been more appropriate in a chat room, then I can still delete the comments and there's no harm done.

Comment: @David please one last question: if I find a similar example but with abstract modules chould I take my $k$ as $k(x)=x\otimes e$ with $e$ is the canonical basis?? thanks

Comment: It won't always work. The argument here to show that $ab \otimes 1 = a \otimes b$ was specific to $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, I don't know what you mean in saying that $\{e\}$ is a "canonical basis." $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. $\{1\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, but not as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, it seems clear now